# How to determine when a not-paid booking has to be made available again?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cookies, cron

I'm having troubles with something that I underestimated and thought that it was an easy thing to be done. So here it is:

#### The task

I have to create a booking system (as WordPress/Woocommerce plugin) where the users have to select available date from a calendar and then choose available hour (each hour can be booked by only one user). After this the users have to go through a payment process and after successful payment the booking will be confirmed.

#### The Database structure

Here is simplified version of what I have as a data base structure:

```
+----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
| id | user_id | meeting_id |  start_date  |  end_date  |
+----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
|  1 |       0 |          0 | 1531591200   | 1531593000 |
+----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

#### A scenario

A user **A.V.** is making a booking. (S)he will select one available date (id 1). To prevent this booking to show as available for anybody else I will mark it in the database as reserved (*not sure how, may be the database needs one more column for this purpose*).  But for some reason **A.V.** is not going to finish the payment process. Let's say that (s)he is going to leave the browser opened for the next 3-4 hours and don't come back to this particular page.

#### The problem

The problem is more architectural (or may be logical) then a coding one. It's this, that the booking is not paid (and might not get paid at all) and it's not available for anybody else to book it. So I got those two questions for myself:

- What to do with this reserved booking?
- How to do it?

The first one is the easy one. I can add a notice to the page that if the user doesn't complete the payment within an hour their reserved booking will be terminated.
But **How to do this**?

#### Some sort of solutions

The first thing that came to my mind was that I have to create a JS function that will be called from `onbeforeunload` event. This function will make a AJAX call to 'release' the reserved booking. Also I would need some `cookie` to store the currently reserved booking which will help me to determine which element from the database was reserved. But this will work only when the users close the browser or the tab. It won't work in the case of the example where A.V is hanging around the web and have left the page, but haven't closed it yet.

So I would need a `cron job` that will run every hour and will search for each booking that has been reserved for more then an hour and then makes it again available. But this might not work well as if a booking is create just after the cron task was finished then the next time it the cron run it will see that this current booking is just less then an hour long and skip it until the next run/hour.

And also I can make a JS function that will start a countdown once the users finish with picking up the date and hour for their booking. But this might not work as expected as the browsers are suspending such functions when the users are moving to another tab... and to be honest, I think, this is not going to work well.

---

I have the feeling that I'm overcomplicating the whole process and would be really grateful for insights on this issue.

Comment: This is off-topic here at SO, we help with written code (mainly) and the answer to your question is way too broad.

Comment: So do I. How do the tutorials do it?

Comment: If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Shouldn't you keep track when the booking process started? Can be kept in database, or with in memory cache set to expire at certain times.

Comment: @LGSon sorry if I haven't made my question clearer. I don't need any one to write down the code for me. I can do this by myself. What I need is some advise on what is the right approach to deal with this problem. Do I need to use cookies at all, or should I use cron job? Is there any need of JS code that will set some countdown timer.
And no SO is not about written code - check the first two question from [the tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @ale I said _mainly_ about written code, and as any answer to your question will be primarily based on that users opinion, it is off-topic, and the question you referred to on tour page, is about a specific problem and not about guidance.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments have said, this seems a bit off topic. None the less, the problem is a fairly easy one to solve - but I think you are taking the wrong approach.

> The first thing that came to my mind was that I have to create a JS function that will be called from onbeforeunload event. This function will make a AJAX call to 'release' the reserved booking.

You can't rely on onbeforeunload - some browsers allow settings to disable it entirely, and it does not work as intended if your user force-closer the browser, or losses cellular reception.

Instead - make this a more of a "human" solution. When someone first selects the hour "block" they want - in your database, have a column for "Prelim-Reserved-Until" and one for "Prelim-reserved-by".

When your user first selects the hour block they want, start a 10 minute timer - and tell the user that they have 10 minutes to finalize the transaction before it is available to others again. While a block has someone who has preliminary reserved it, don't show it to other users or allow them to purchase the block until after that period.

Additional functionality could include "refreshing" the 10 minutes if the user continues through the multi-stage-checkout, as well as notifying them after the 10 minutes is up and allowing them to manually request another 10 minutes or such. Of course you might want some verification, maybe only allowing one user or one IP to "hold" a block at any given time, or allowing them only so many holds per day.

Comment: Thank you. The idea of the refreshing the page is a good one.